# perl + export param in to perl syntax in shell script

Tags: perl

I have the following script that replace `a` param to `b` param and match only the `c` parameter in line
how to change the perl syntax: `if /$c/` in order to export c param to the follwoing perl syntax

```
#!/bin/bash
export a='@d&' 
export b='new text' 
export c='bla bla'
echo $LINE |  perl -pe 'next if /^#/; s/(^|\s)\Q$ENV{a}\E(\s|$)/$1$ENV{b}$2/ if /$c/'
```

example of line

```
parameter=@d&
```

when `c` is the *parameter*

Comment: Put your code under code blocks.

Comment: yael, http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need is

```
if /$ENV{c}/
```

And please format your code properly